# search value for key in file using python

Tags: python

I am new to Python.

Scenario:

- apple=gravity search this pattern in file
- search for apple if exist fetch corresponding value for apple,
- if it is apple=gravity then case pass .

  file structure (test.txt )

  car=stop
     green=go
    apple=gravity

Please provide some suggestions as to how I can search value for key in file using Python

Sample:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
wordCheck="apple=gravity";
for line in f:
    if 'wordCheck' == line:
        print ('found')
    else:
        print ('notfound')
    break
```

Comment: Change the beginning of your for loop to this:
    `for line in f.readlines():`

Comment: `line.split("=")` will give you lists like `['car', 'stop']` so you can test `if line.split("=")[0] == "apple"`

Comment: @ErikBrodyDreyer: No, do not do that. Why would you want to do that? That replaces an efficient loop over the file object with one that reads everything into a list first. What a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split your line with `=`

Check if `apple` is present in your first index! If true then, print the second index!

**Note:** 
While reading lines from file, the '\n' character will be present. To get your line without `\n` read you content from file and use splitlines()!

To make it clean, strip the spaces from the beginning and end of your line to avoid glitches caused by spaces at the beginning and end of your line!

That is,

```
f = open('test.txt', 'r')
for line in map(str.strip,f.read().splitlines()):
    line = line.split('=')
    if 'apple' == line[0]:
        print line[1]
    else:
        print ('notfound')
```

Output:

```
notfound
notfound
gravity
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Don't read the whole file into memory first. Just `line = line.strip().split('=')` instead.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But OP bring a newbie here I don't think the file would be that big to handle it in a more pythonic way.

Comment: Thanks it's helps a lot

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran: why should someone new to Python *not* learn proper file handling from the start? Why teach bad habits (reading the file in one go) when the rest of the loop only needs access to one line at a time?

Comment: Memory used could be reduced by reading lines, that is `f.readlines()` and the stripping the trailing `\n` character. Other than that I dont see any problem in using f.read().splitlines() to read small files!

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through the file directly as you are doing, is just fine, and considered more 'Pythonic' than `readlines()` (or indeed `read().splitlines()`).

Here, I strip the newline from each line and then split by the `=` to get the two halves.
Then, I test for the check word, and if present print out the other half of the line.

Note also that I have used the `with` context manager to open the file. This makes sure that the file is closed, even if an exception occurs.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    wordcheck="apple"
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.strip().split('=')
        if wordcheck == key:
            print (val)
        else:
            print ('notfound')
```